# simplify check for $? return code

Tags: bash, shell-script

In my script I have the following:

```
$cmd arg1 arg2 >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
   # cmd succeeds, do something
fi
```

Is there a way to make it shorter? I checked `man test` for various options in `[]` command, but could not find anything that could make it shorter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can act on the return of the command directly

```
if cmd arg1 arg2 >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  do-the-things
fi
```

If it returns 0 it will be true, anything other than 0 will be false.

You can read about [conditional constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs) in the bash manual

Comment: You can even `$cmd arg1 arg2 && do-the-things`.